# Making a list for each cell in a datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a 9x9 DataGridView and each cell can only contain a number between 1-9 (like sudoku). I wish to have some sort of list for each cell containing all 9 of these numbers. As the game goes on i will need to start removing numbers from different cell's "list". could i get some advice on what i should use in this situation? is there a way of avoiding making 81 different lists and manually inserting all 9 numbers into all 81 lists?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
  {
    string listname;
    listname = "cell" + i.ToString() + j.ToString();
    List<int> listname = new List<int>();
  }
}
```

I was thinking something like this would help with making the 81 different lists as the list names would be cell(rownum)(columnnum) but this obviously doesn't work.

Comment: How about creating an enum with a flags attribute, assigning One = 1, Two = 2, Three = 4, Four = 8 .. Nine = 256. Then create a 9x9 array of these enums, initialising each value with 511 (all the bits 1 to 9). Then to remove a number, you simply NOT it from the enum. Much easier than 81 lists!

Comment: sorry i dont know much about enums is there a webpage you reccomend to learn more about it? @JonathanWillcock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you an idea of what I mean, create yourself an enumeration like the following:

```
[Flags]
public enum SudokuValue
{
    None = 0,
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 4,
    Four = 8,
    Five = 16,
    Six = 32,
    Seven = 64,
    Eight = 128,
    Nine = 256
}
```

The Flags attribute is important, as we shall see later.  You can now take advantage of this enumeration in a class looking something like:

```
public class SudokuHelper
{
    private SudokuValue[,] gridValues;
    private bool[,] gridFills;

    public SudokuHelper()
    {
        gridValues = new SudokuValue[9, 9];
        gridFills = new bool[9, 9];
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            {
                gridValues[i, j] = (SudokuValue)511;
                gridFills[i, j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    public void UpdateGrid(int row, int col, int val)
    {
        gridFills[row, col] = true;
        SudokuValue sudoku = (SudokuValue)(Math.Pow(2, val - 1));
        gridValues[row, col] = sudoku;
        //Update same col
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            if (!gridFills[i, col] &&  gridValues[i, col].HasFlag(sudoku))
            {
                gridValues[i, col] -= sudoku;
            }
        }
        //Update same col
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            if (!gridFills[row, i] && gridValues[row, i].HasFlag(sudoku))
            {
                gridValues[row, i] -= sudoku;
            }
        }
        //Update same block
        int startBlockRow;
        int startBlockCol;
        if (row < 3)
        {
            startBlockRow = 0;
        }
        else if (row < 6)
        {
            startBlockRow = 3;
        }
        else
        {
            startBlockRow = 6;
        }
        if (col < 3)
        {
            startBlockCol = 0;
        }
        else if (col < 6)
        {
            startBlockCol = 3;
        }
        else
        {
            startBlockCol = 6;
        }
        for (int i = startBlockRow; i < startBlockRow + 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = startBlockCol; j < startBlockCol + 3; j++)
            {
                if (!gridFills[i, j] && gridValues[i,j].HasFlag(sudoku))
                {
                    gridValues[i, j] -= sudoku;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public string GetStringRepresentation(int row, int col)
    {
        var sB = new StringBuilder();
        if (gridValues[row, col].HasFlag(SudokuValue.One))
        {
            sB.Append(",1");
        }
        if (gridValues[row, col].HasFlag(SudokuValue.Two))
        {
            sB.Append(",2");
        }
        if (gridValues[row, col].HasFlag(SudokuValue.Three))
        {
            sB.Append(",3");
        }
        if (gridValues[row, col].HasFlag(SudokuValue.Four))
        {
            sB.Append(",4");
        }
        if (gridValues[row, col].HasFlag(SudokuValue.Five))
        {
            sB.Append(",5");
        }
        if (gridValues[row, col].HasFlag(SudokuValue.Six))
        {
            sB.Append(",6");
        }
        if (gridValues[row, col].HasFlag(SudokuValue.Seven))
        {
            sB.Append(",7");
        }
        if (gridValues[row, col].HasFlag(SudokuValue.Eight))
        {
            sB.Append(",8");
        }
        if (gridValues[row, col].HasFlag(SudokuValue.Nine))
        {
            sB.Append(",9");
        }
        //remove leading comma
        return sB.ToString().Substring(1);
    }
}
```

The constructor creates an initial two-dimensional array of SudokuValues and populates it with an initial value representing all the possible values 1 ... 9 (511).  Note that although 511 is not listed within the enumeration, we can still cast it to a SudokuValue.  This is because all enumerations are by default integers.  It also creates and populates a two-dimensional array of bools, to represent those cells for which values have been provided.

It then provides a method to update the values in the grid, if a value is entered into one  of the cells.  This method takes three parameters, the row and column of the updated cell, and the value entered into the cell as an integer (necessarily 1 .. 9).  First of all it updates the cell itself in the grid (effectively wiping all the other possibilities), and sets the boolean flag.  It then proceeds to remove the entered value as a possibility in the other cells in the same column, the same row, and the same 3x3 block.  Here it checks before removing the value, that the value previously still was there (using the HasFlags method - available because we set the Flags attribute above), to avoid the cell being entered twice.  A little trick here: the entered value (1 .. 9) can be converted to its enumeration equivalent, by reducing it by 1 and then taking 2 to the resulting power.

Finally the helper provides a textual representation of what any given cell contains (either a single value if set, or the remaining possibilities).

To test this, we can do something like this (I was using a WinForms app to test hence the MessageBox.Show()):

```
var sH = new SudokuHelper();
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    var sB = new StringBuilder();
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        sB.Append(" ; " + sH.GetStringRepresentation(i, j));
    }
    MessageBox.Show($"Row {i}: " + sB.ToString().Substring(3));
}

sH.UpdateGrid(4, 7, 9);
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    var sB = new StringBuilder();
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        sB.Append(" ; " + sH.GetStringRepresentation(i, j));
    }
    MessageBox.Show($"Row {i}: " + sB.ToString().Substring(3));
}
```

If it was me building this app, I would use a 9x9 grid of TextBoxes (rather than a DataGridView), all with a KeyDown/KeyPress event, that calls the SudokuHelper to update the Grid if one of the keys 1 .. 9 is pressed.  But maybe you need a DataGridView for other reasons?

Comment: thanks so much for the help!! yes i needed to use a datagridview as microsoft access is involved. this method seems much easier than what i was trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Make your columns DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. This way every cell in these columns will be a DataGridViewcomboBoxCell.

Property DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DataSource and DataGridViewComboBoxCell.DataSource contain all possible values. Initially set your column DataSource to all initial values, after your cells are created, you can limit the values in the Cells datasource.

```
class SudokuRow
{
    public int C0 {get; set;}
    public int C1 {get; set;}
    public int C2 {get; set;}

    public int C3 {get; set;}
    public int C4 {get; set;}
    public int C5 {get; set;}

    public int C6 {get; set;}
    public int C7 {get; set;}
    public int C8 {get; set;}
}
```

Use visual studio designer to add some columns in a dummy project to see which
properties should be filled

```
DataGridView dgvSudoku = new DataGridView()
for (int i=0; i<9; ++i)
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    column.Name = "column" + i.ToString();
    column.DataPropertyName = "C" + i.ToString();
    ...
    column.DataSource = enumerable.Range(1,9).ToList();  // allowed values
    dgvSudoko.Columns.Add(column);
}
```

If you want to add a blank, then don't add numbers, but the character 0..9 and blank.
The sudokuRow contains char instead of int.

If you use DataBinding to display the items, and you want it one-direction only, you can use a List to assign to the DataSource. However, if you want to read operator input, you'll have to put the data in a BindingList.

```
private BindingList<SudokuRow> SudokuData
{
    get => (BindingList<SudokuRow>)this.dgvSudoku.DataSource;
    set => this.dgvSudokuy.DataSource = value;
}
```

Now initialize your datagridview:

```
List<SudokuData> initialSudokuData = ...
this.SudokuData = initialSudokuData;
```

After some operatorinput you want to limit the possibilities of a cell:

```
LimitPossibilites(DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell, IEnumerable<int> allowedValues)
{
    // TODO: what to do if current value is not allowed?

    // limit the combobox values
    cell.DataSource = new BindingList<int>(allowedValues.ToList());
}
```

Or if you don't want to replace the BindingList with a new BindingList, consider to add / remove items using `Bindling<T>` properties. However, that seems to be more work.
}